# Issue with angular2 router' resolve being executed twice

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I have got an issue with my configuration of **angular2 router's** `Routes` whereby a `resolve` is executed twice although defined only once.

Here is my `Routes` definition:

```
export const AppRoutes: Routes = [
  {path: '', component: HomeComponent},
  {
    path: 'dashboard',
    component: DashboardComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        component: DashboardSummaryComponent,
        resolve: {
          userAccount: UserAccountResolve
        }
      },
      ...
```

When I navigate to `'/dashboard'` as follows:

```
this.router.navigate(['/dashboard'])
```

The resolve for `DashboardSummaryComponent` (i.e. `UserAccountResolve`) is executed twice...

Can someone please explain why? Is this to be expected?

**edit 1**: <strike>It must be noted that `UserAccountResolve` is actually an **http** call. Also, the first call (the one that fails) results in a `401` error.</strike> (this seems to be irrelevant to the issue)

**edit 2**: The issue is probably related to the use of child components but I was not able to find relevant information in the angular 2 documentation about how resolves are dealt with by child/parent components...

Answer (score 1):

Could be related to [Router 3.2.0 - Providers instantiated twice](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/12869)

Try downgrading @angular/router to ~3.1.0

Answer (score 1):

This issue is fixed in Angular 4.0